# SSIS Workflow issue when run by Task Scheduler

Tags: ssis, odbc, scheduled-tasks, impala

I have a SSIS Workflow that is a little unreliable.

The Normal procedure should be as follows: Task Scheduler Job starts batch File. Batch File starts SSIS Job.

This process produces this error:

```
Error: 2020-12-08 07:10:43.95


Code: 0xC02090F5
   Source: Data Flow Task Connect to Impala [2132]
   Description: The component "Connect to Impala" (2132) was unable to process the data. ERROR [08S01] [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (120) Error while retrieving data from in Impala: [08S01] : SSL_read: error code: 0
End Error
Error: 2020-12-08 07:10:43.95
   Code: 0xC0047038
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Connect to Impala" (2132) returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
```

But when I start the Batch File, the SSIS Job is executed successfully. Even when I start the Job within MS Visual Studio there are no issues.

Google makes a hint that there could be an issue with the ODBC connection. I am using an 32 Bit ODBC Driver for Impala (User DSN). Also tried it with 64 Bit but doesn't work either.

I appreciate every answer.
Thanks

Comment: If you've created a User DSN but are running the job as anyone but that user, the job user won't have the DSN defined/accessible for them. You'd likely need to create it under their account or switch to a System DSN. (and mirror the bit'edness when you execute the job - advanced settings, 32 bit mode) The other thing to check is whether there's a one-time task like accepting a certificate that needs to be done on the execution account

Comment: Hi @billinkc, thanks. I run the job via User DSN and only with the one user where the DSN is configured. System DSN still does not work, neither for that nor for another. I am not sure whether there is sth. like accepting a certificate. What could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Please see this solution: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/ERROR-SSL-read-error-code-0-with-IMPALA-from-R-programming/td-p/280561

It is about timeout parameters.